# Оператор выбора в С нелогичный

Tags: c

Всем известно поведение оператора **switch** в C, где завершение его действия нужно делать оператором **break**. Но по стандарту этого можно не делать, тогда выполняются все последующие блоки безусловно, до первого break! **Почему именно так ?** Ведь двоеточием задается множество значений выбора, которое игнорировать, по смыслу, нельзя. Подскажите пожалуйста хотя бы один реальный алгоритм где можно было бы использовать эту странную особенность.

Comment: Ну, например, в Go выбрана модель без "проваливания" к другому case, но и там оставлена такая возможность - специальное ключевое слово...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да нет вопросов :) [Оптимизация Даффа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B0)

```
strcpy(char* to, char* from, int count)
{
    int n = (count + 7) / 8;
    if (!count) return;
    switch (count % 8) {
    case 0: do { *to++ = *from++;
    case 7:      *to++ = *from++;
    case 6:      *to++ = *from++;
    case 5:      *to++ = *from++;
    case 4:      *to++ = *from++;
    case 3:      *to++ = *from++;
    case 2:      *to++ = *from++;
    case 1:      *to++ = *from++;
               } while (--n > 0);
    }
}
```

Вдогонку: вероятно, сделан именно `break`, а не какой-то `nobreak`, потому что тогда не работала бы распространенная конструкция с множественными `case`, типа

```
case 0:
case 2:
case 4:
case 8:
    Работа с четными
    break;
case 1:
case 3:
case 5:
case 7:
case 9:
    Работа с нечетными
    break;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Странный, вычурный и бесполезный метод.

Comment: Ну, смотря **когда**. В **те** времена был вполне разумен.

Comment: Да, это уже искусство а не инженеринг.

Comment: я и сейчас такое использовал :) на олимпиаде иногда проще ногой упихать чем решение нормальное найти :)

Answer (score 4):

Вспомним, для чего еще используется двоеточие в C. Для задания меток для goto. `switch` можно рассматривать как `goto` на определенную метку внутри цикла выполняющегося один раз. Выполнение начинается с точи входа - с места куда передал управление `goto` и продолжается до конца блока (закрывающегося `}`) или инструкции явного выхода из блока `break`.

Следующий код:

```
switch(x) {
 case 1:
         a=5;
 case 2: b=3; break;
 case 3: a=7; b=10; break;
 default: a=b=0;
}
```

Можно рассматривать как:

```
do {
         if(x==1) goto case1;
    else if(x==2) goto case2;
    else if(x==3) goto case3;
    else          goto case_default;

    case1: a=5;
    case2: b=3; break;
    case3: a=7; b=10; break;
    case_default: a=b=0;
   } while(0);
```

Для чего используется ... Везде где некий блок кода надо выполнить для нескольких условий, но при этом при выполнении данных условий есть и особенности. Причем, с точки зрения процессора, т.е. языка ассемблера, подобное представление кода наиболее логично и рационально, так как уменьшает количество условных переходов.

Comment: Да, так проще но это не соответствует семантике описания. Нужно знать, что после отсутствующего `break` последующие `case`-ы игнорируются.

Comment: @Вячеслав Ну да, это надо знать. Иначе никак. Для человека не знакомого с ассемблером конструкция интуитивно не понятна. А вот когда знаешь ассемблер и потом переходишь на C она кажется абсолютно логичной и интуитивно понятной. Потому как в асм если после блока кода не стоит явного `jmp`(или `br` в некоторых платформах) для перехода в другую точку код продолжает выполнятся дальше не взирая на то, что стоят точки входа, которые по счастливому совпадению так же выглядят как `case1:`. Очень может быть, что именно этим и руководствовались, когда придумывали switch

Answer (score 3):

Всё очень даже логично. **Switch** содержит блоки действий и метки, определяющие, где начать выполнение. Делается это просто: программа идёт, находит `case` с подходящим значением и начинает выполнение всего кода до `break` или конца switch'a. То есть, метками задаётся именно место для старта выполнения при соответствии значений, а не блок для выполнения только при соответствии значений.

Польза: есть у Вас *x*, при его значении 0 нужно выполнить действие A, при его значении 1 выполнить *A и B*, при значении 2 выполнить C:

```
switch (x) {
case 1:
    doB();
case 0:
    doA();
    break;
case 2:
    doC();
    break;
}
```

На практике такое не часто, но иногда бывает реально полезным. А вообще, код вроде `case 0: case 1:` является тем же самым, только после первой метки нет действий.

Comment: Возможно я плохо изложил мысль. Оператор `case A:` по сути выполняет сравнение `A` с `x`. Последовательность `case A: case B: ...` задает множество сравнений объединенных по ИЛИ, блок выполняется при совпадении хотя бы одной из констант. **Но почему игнорируются все последующие операторы `case` ?**

Comment: @Вячеслав потому что так и было задумано :) Нет ИЛИ, при выполнении проверки, результат которой истинен, больше проверок не происходит, просто выполняется весь код до _break'a_.

Comment: Ленивое ИЛИ так и работает. Да так сложилось. :)

Comment: В том и дело, что Вы смотрите на это как на ИЛИ. Действительно него похоже, но оно не может дать ответа на Ваш вопрос и объяснить поведение оператора. Потому что здесь чуть другая механика, кейсы не объединяются в одну проверку, что и позволяет между ними вставлять блоки кода.

Comment: Я не об этом спрашивал.

Comment: @Вячеслав почему именно так? Вероятно, простота реализации и чуть большая эффективность, чем если просто переводить в набор if'ов с набором _или_. Получается конечный автомат с двумя состояниями: последовательная проверка всех меток и выполнение кода после успешного сравнения.

Comment: Да, этот вопрос следовало бы задать Кену и Денису.